# POSIX callbacks and NSAutoreleasePool with ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, posix, nsautoreleasepool

According to this Apple [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsautoreleasepool_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I've read that when interacting with Cocoa on a POSIX thread that I should create a `NSAutoreleasePool`.

> If you are making Cocoa calls outside of the Application Kit’s main
>   thread—for example if you create a Foundation-only application or if
>   you detach a thread—you need to create your own autorelease pool.

Unfortunately, using `NSAutoreleasePool` is disallowed in ARC.

What should I do then to guarantee that there is always an pool available for any ARC code that is autoreleased?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`@autoreleasepool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-SW5).

```
@autoreleasepool
{
    // make Cocoa calls here
}
```

This allows the compiler to reason properly about the lifetime of objects that cross the pool's boundary, which is a requirement for ARC. (That's why you can't use `NSAutoreleasePool`.) As a bonus, it's also faster.